# secondary monitor resolution went off suddenly on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. I have connected a VGA monitor (Acer) to this laptop as my laptop screen is broken.

Everything was fine, until one fine day my monitor went blank and I had to reboot the laptop.

Once I got the gui I found that my secondary vga monitor is not working. Ubuntu is not able to set the resolution to higher 16:9.

Seems it is not able to find the right driver for this secondary monitor.

Below is the output from dmesg.

```
[   20.877170] sony_laptop: Sony Notebook Control Driver v0.6
[   20.877386] input: Sony Vaio Keys as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/SNY5001:00/input/input7
[   20.885435] input: Sony Vaio Jogdial as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/SNY5001:00/input/input8
[   20.888589] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   20.904629] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[   20.904635] checking generic (b0000000 410000) vs hw (b0000000 10000000)
[   20.904637] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
[   20.904657] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   20.923223] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   20.938996] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   20.962842] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   20.962854] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   20.962855] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   20.962912] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   20.999456] kvm: disabled by bios
[   21.008370] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307
[   21.008374] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues.
[   21.008375] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this.
[   21.039348] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
```

Please help me solve this issue!

Thank You!

**Update:** I ran command `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x900` and resolution is alright now. But now I see two screens one in each other. My primary laptop monitor is not working, that's why I use secondary VGA monitor. But now both the screens are one in each other, and task bar on top is overlapped because of this.

Output of `xrandr` command now is as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have attached a screenshot for this:

[image]

Comment: Are any BIOS updates available for this laptop? Are you running the latest kernel? `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` if you aren't. What is the output from `xrandr`? Are the monitor cables plugged in ok?

Comment: I don't think there is any BIOS update for Sony VAIO. I am updating my kernel version through above command. I have 14.04 which I thought to keep as its a long term support release. Will updating the OS release solve my problem?

Comment: and this is the output for xrandr:

Comment: xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9

Comment: VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900       60.0 +
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1*    70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: Please don't put complicated text in a comment, instead add it to the question so the formatting is preserved.

Comment: What is the resolution of your monitor? Try `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x900`

Comment: For some reason it appears both your displays are set to 1024x768 but xrandr is reporting that isn't the preferred resolution for either. Are the displays mirrored? What if you do `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output VGA1 --off; sleep 5; xrandr --output VGA1 --auto`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got the right resolution for the secondary monitor. Also the over lapping display was sorted out, when I pressed the 'toggle output display' key on my laptop.